# Is there a way to extract a deckgl layer in mapbox layer format

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl

I am using plain javascript so please no react deckgl answers.

I need to get the image of the map with the deckgl layer cloud point layer.  Currently I am using mapbox static API to download the map image withing a set bounding box. I am downloading the map image like this using the mapbox static api `url + bboxString +` /${height}x${width}?access_token=${scope.apiKey}&attribution=false&logo=false.

In the attached image you can see the blue square representing the bounding box.  You can also see the point cloud in red.[image]  You can pass a mapbox layer to the mapbox static api and download a map with the additional layer.  However, the deckgl layer is not in the format of a mapbox layer

Example mapbox layer with a polygon from geojson.

```
map.addSource('maine', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': {
'type': 'Feature',
'geometry': {
'type': 'Polygon',
// These coordinates outline Maine.
'coordinates': [
[
[-67.13734, 45.13745],
[-66.96466, 44.8097],
[-68.03252, 44.3252],
[-69.06, 43.98],
[-70.11617, 43.68405],
[-70.64573, 43.09008],
[-70.75102, 43.08003],
[-70.79761, 43.21973],
[-70.98176, 43.36789],
[-70.94416, 43.46633],
[-71.08482, 45.30524],
[-70.66002, 45.46022],
[-70.30495, 45.91479],
[-70.00014, 46.69317],
[-69.23708, 47.44777],
[-68.90478, 47.18479],
[-68.2343, 47.35462],
[-67.79035, 47.06624],
[-67.79141, 45.70258],
[-67.13734, 45.13745]
]
]
}
}
});
```

```
map.addLayer({
'id': 'maine',
'type': 'fill',
'source': 'maine', // reference the data source
'layout': {},
'paint': {
'fill-color': '#0080ff', // blue color fill
'fill-opacity': 0.5
}
});
```